# Why is Pandas Module still not found after downloading Anaconda?

Tags: pandas, anaconda

Recently I've installed Anaconda to my machine, so that it would include the Pandas module. Currently I'm running a Mac with an Intel chip.

After opening a Python session in Terminal and typing import pandas, here is the error message I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Will

Comment: In order to utilize Python within the Anaconda environment, you need to run within the anaconda environment, you can't do that directly from the terminal as you have illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `pandas` library as well in order to use it in Python. You can install it via `pip` in the Anaconda terminal:

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: if they are using anaconda, then `conda install pandas` is the way to go